# Folder color not working

Tags: directory, colors

I've installed folder color in  Ubuntu 20.04, GNOME using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:costales/folder-color
sudo apt install folder-color -y
nautilus -q
```

but it only allows me to change emblems, not color. When I right-click at a folder, the color submenu only shows five emblems to choose.

[image: screenshot of the menu]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some context. Which Ubuntu are you using? Which desktop environment? How are you using this tool? Can you maybe show a screenshot?

Comment: @terdon done, added changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt purge folder-color
sudo apt update
sudo apt install folder-color -y
nautilus -q
```

I *think* that’s how I solved the problem, but honestly I also tried some other things so I’m not so sure...